# Is there ever a reason to query ioctl for hardware info when we have sysfs?

Tags: kernel, hardware, sysfs, ioctl

My assumption is that `sysfs` is built using `ioctl` queries, meaning all the information you would want (or at least most of it) is already available by simply reading files on `sysfs`. I notice some programs (e.g., `hdparm`) still use `ioctl` calls rather than simply hitting `sysfs` , and I'm curious if there's a reason for that. Is `sysfs` unreliable? If you're only interested in hardware info, is there a reason to use `ioctl` over `sysfs`?

Comment: `sysfs` is *not* built using `ioctl` queries.
`ioctl` and `sysfs` are two separate and fundamentally different mechanisms for accessing kernel data structures and functions. `sysfs` is considered more modern, so whenever possible use `sysfs`.

Comment: Is there a way to tell when I should use sysfs vs ioctl? E.g., trying to get information on a hard drive (size, make/model, etc), is there a situation where that info would not be in sysfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rightly asserted by Tilman in comments, sysfs and ioctl both provide userland access to kernel data structures.
Since the kernel does not need system calls to access to its own data, neither is the sysfs tree built resorting to ioctl calls, nor any user action on its *files* will translate into ioctl calls.

---

You write *" … information is already available by **simply** reading files…"* and this is, I believe, the answer for your final question :

Why **can** it appear simpler to resort to the sysfs interface ?

- First because considered in front of your basic ASCII terminal running some shell, the sysfs tree gives access to (binary) kernel data via the most basic cat and echo commands.
- Thanks to other basic shell commands, (ls, cd) you can also, following the symlinks get some deep understanding of the relationships between kernel objects.
- On top of this the user can take benefits from some (at least minimal) control over the validity of the changes you would wish to commit.

This indeed makes sysfs the right way to go when, under console, wishing to tune your system, write scripts or rules, confortabely debug some driver from userspace (the initial destination of sysfs… just think that before… /dev/mem was your only friend for that later purpose.)

All right then, however, there are cases you just don't care of all these facilities, cases where accessing kernel objects via the sysfs interface would just constrain you to… write (much) more code : When writing a C program :
Just imagine : You want to open some file, transcode your data, manage additional error conditions, deal with race conditions ? When a simple ioctl system call is enough (providing you know what you are doing of course).

So you had the answer to your question : When should you prefer this or that way ? Simply because for you, here and now, achieving what you want to achieve will be much simpler using this rather than that.